# Reactjs not updating the State in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-state

I am developing a simple application in reactS. The main purpose of the app is it will show some cards and on search, cards will be filtered and selective cards will be displayed. I am sharing the code of App.js.
I have a file name 'Robots.js'

```
import './App.css';
import CardList from './Components/CardList';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import {Robots} from './Components/Robots';

function App() {

  const [robots,setRobots] = useState({
    robo:Robots,
    search:''
  });

  const onSearchChange = (e) =>{
    setRobots({...robots,search:e.target.value});
    const filteredRobots = robots.robo.filter(item=>{return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(robots.search.toLowerCase())});
    //setRobots({...robots,robo:filteredRobots});
    console.log(filteredRobots);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header onSearchChange={onSearchChange} />
      <CardList Robots={robots.robo}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If I comment
`setRobots({...robots,robo:filteredRobots});`
this line on console I can show array is reducing its number of items but with that line it just does nothing. I think it makes sense it should do.
I hope I made my point clear.

Comment: `useEffect(()=> setRobots({
    robo:Robots,
    search:''
  }),[Robots])` try adding this

Comment: React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'Robots'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'Robots' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component

Answer (score 1):

You can update the state in one go as shown below:

```js
const onSearchChange = (e) => {

  const filteredRobots = robots.robo.filter(item => {
    return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(robots.search.toLowerCase())
  });

  console.log(filteredRobots);

  setRobots({
    robo: filteredRobots,
    search: e.target.value
  });

}
```

Since you only have two properties you can just create a new object with those properties and don't really need spread operator.

Comment: I have a query. This way cards will filter successfully but on backspace(deleting letters) it stuck on that filtered card means when we have empty textfield it should show all the cards but it is display only the filtered one.
Please guide me about this too.
Thanks

Comment: Something like `if(e.target.value === '') { filteredRobots = Robots}`. Prob need to make `filteredRobots` a `let`

Comment: Or `robo: e.target.value? filteredRobots : Robots`

Comment: It only worked when textField is empty but to perform a live search means deleting some letters it should show more cards. is not happening I think I make my point clear. Thanks for finding a solution for me

Comment: l

App.js:32 (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

App.js:31 le
App.js:32 (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
App.js:31 lea
App.js:32 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
App.js:31 lean
App.js:32 [{…}]
App.js:31 lea
App.js:32 [{…}]
App.js:31 le
App.js:32 [{…}]
App.js:31 l
App.js:32 [{…}]
App.js:31 
App.js:32 (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: This is the issue i have checked from the console. on reducing character array does not grow again once it gets filtered.

Comment: Create two states, `const [robots,setRobots] = useState({...})` and `const [filteredRobots,setFilteredRobots] = useState({...})` and always create `filteredRobots` from  `robots` state which always contains all robots. This will fix the issue

Comment: Sorry it is not working either this way. Can you please give it a look if you have time.
https://github.com/JawadAli130/RobotApp

Comment: You can use https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new for sharing this like this

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-almeida-kyw14?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have added the code here is it visible to you? Thanks for your time again

Comment: Try this https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-morse-1pkvs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it is working but sorry not accurate as it should be. For Example On pressing 'l' it shows 10 cards but one of the cards doesn't contain any 'l'. Secondly on typing 'lea' ==> 5 cards are there, on 'lean' ==> 1 card and on removing 'n' there is still one card but there must be 5.
I don't know whats happening

Comment: Your data set of have 1 card that matches "lea ", I don't know how you expect to see 5. Anyway that is up-to your filtering logic. I think I answered your original question and a lot of follow ups, If you need help with filtering logic, please ask another question. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

The `setRobots` run "asynchronous" - therefore if you have:

```
const[data, setData] = setState(5);

const update = (newData) => {
   setData(1);
   console.log(data) // will print 5
}
```

And only in the second render its will print 1

you can read more in here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

In your implementation you have a problem that you don't save the original array of the cards

So first save the original array

```
// Here will be the full list of cards.
const [cards, setCards] = useState(allCards);

// Here will be the search by text
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

// Here will be all the filtered cards
// If you don't know whats useMemo is you can look in here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo
const filteredCards = useMemo(()=>{
   return cards.filter((card) => 
      card.item.toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()));

},[cards, search])

// on search changed callback 
const onSearchChange = (e)=>{setSearch(e.target.value || '')}

// then return your component 
  return (
    <div>
      <Header onSearchChange={onSearchChange} />
      <CardList Robots={filteredCards}/>
    </div>
  );
```